# getting 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint' error with migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Tried to create 3 tables that are permissions, users_roles and permission_role. But I got an error when migrating.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `permission_role` add constraint `permission_role_permission_id_foreign` foreign key (`permission_id`) references `permissions` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Here are my migrations:

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('user_id');            
            $table->nullableTimestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('definition')->nullable();
           
            $table->nullableTimestamps();            
        });       
    }   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users_roles');
        Schema::dropIfExists('permissions');
    }
```

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->nullableTimestamps();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('users_roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('permission_roles');
    }
```

I use unsigned() and not understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You didn't mention your laravel version. Anyway, use bigInteger `$table->bigInteger('permission_id')->unsigned();` also for role_id. Also change your all praimary key `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->bigIncrements('id');`

Comment: it works! thanks but why they should start with 'big'

Answer (score 1):

Because Laravel 5.8 Added `bigIncrements` and `bigInteger` as defaults. There is one change in Laravel 5.8 that is not mentioned in the official upgrade guide.

There are two ways to fix it :

Change original **increments()** to **bigIncrements**
And in your foreign key column do **bigInteger()** instead of **integer()**